# Import text or Excel file with title and text in separate columns into PowerPoint (one slide per row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, text-editing

It is easy enough to open a text file in PowerPoint such that the data on each line is imported as title in a separate slide. This is great. However, can someone please advise how to import a body text field as well?

For example, say I have an Excel file with this data:
Column A = PowerPoint Title
Column B = PowerPoint text

I need to automatically create separate Title + Text slides for every line of my text/csv/excel file.

Currently, it is easy to copy to a text file and import Column A only, and PowerPoint creates a separate slide for each. Great. But how can I just as easily import Column A title and its associated Column B text so that they are put together on the same slide? i.e. still one slide per row, but more than one column. Currently, if you try to import CSV data with multiple columns, it will include all the data in the row on its own slide, but it will just shove it all in the title, separated by a comma.

There must be a very simple procedural way to achieve this basic import function **without coding or plugins.**

Additionally, it seems that the number of imported lines is limited to 500. Can this be increased?

First time user here - I'm happy to clarify anything you need.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You will need VBA for that, but you seem to reject such a solution.

Comment: >> Additionally, it seems that the number of imported lines is limited to 500. Can this be increased?   No, but IIRC you can break your file into two or more chunks, each < 500 items and import one at a time. If a plain TXT file rather than CSV is an option, put each title on a line by itself, followed by <TAB>Bullet points.  One tab sets the line to top level bullet point, two tabs = second level bullets and so on.

Comment: Thank you harrymc and Steve.

Comment: harrymc yes since I am unfamiliar with VBA and wanted to achieve something fairly simple, I wondered if there was a procedural way that didn't require coding, but it seems there is none, excepting the bullet solution proposed by Steve Rindsberg. I'm guessing that VBA will be worth the time investment at some point.